# cannot get the correct signal voltage from the bldc controller output phase

Tags: arduino, mosfet, signal, brushless-dc-motor, three-phase

I am currently working on a BLDC (Brushless Direct Current) controller project using Arduino to manage a 48V BLDC motor. The controller utilizes a trapezoidal control method, which involves a six-step switching process executed by MOSFETs to instigate the rotation of the BLDC motor. This design has proven successful in simulation, with the output phase appearing as expected.

However, upon conducting a physical test using the same design, the results were not as anticipated. Instead of the correct phased outputs, all three output phases overlapped, as demonstrated in the attached graph. This abnormality in the output phase also seems to have influenced my input. The input, originally a 5V PWM signal, changes to match the incorrect output once the power supply for the MOSFETs is switched on.

Despite thoroughly checking my connections, this issue persists, leaving me perplexed. I am seeking advice on how to rectify this situation.
[image: Gate driver design , there are 3]
[image: The 6 steps mosfet design]
[image: 3 output phase][image: The output phase from real world]